# Why is thread::scope unable to copy primitive types without a move closure?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Given this [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=498cb0a26c9d23731fabfe2ba5925511):

```rust
use std::thread;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ImportantStruct {}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![42, 42, 42, 42];
    let s = ImportantStruct{};
    
    thread::scope(|scope| {
        for (index, foo) in data.drain(..).enumerate() {
            scope.spawn(|| println!("thread {} doing {} while having a borrow on {:?}", index, foo, &s));
        }
    });
}
```

The rust compiler fails with the following error message:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `foo`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:12:25
   |
10 |     thread::scope(|scope| {
   |                    ----- has type `&'1 Scope<'1, '_>`
11 |         for (index, foo) in data.drain(..).enumerate() {
12 |             scope.spawn(|| println!("thread {} doing {} while having a borrow on {:?}", index, foo, &s));
   |                         ^^ may outlive borrowed value `foo`                                    --- `foo` is borrowed here
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'1`
  --> src/main.rs:12:13
   |
12 |             scope.spawn(|| println!("thread {} doing {} while having a borrow on {:?}", index, foo, &s));
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `foo` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
12 |             scope.spawn(move || println!("thread {} doing {} while having a borrow on {:?}", index, foo, &s));
   |                         ++++

error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `index`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:12:25
   |
10 |     thread::scope(|scope| {
   |                    ----- has type `&'1 Scope<'1, '_>`
11 |         for (index, foo) in data.drain(..).enumerate() {
12 |             scope.spawn(|| println!("thread {} doing {} while having a borrow on {:?}", index, foo, &s));
   |                         ^^ may outlive borrowed value `index`                           ----- `index` is borrowed here
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'1`
  --> src/main.rs:12:13
   |
12 |             scope.spawn(|| println!("thread {} doing {} while having a borrow on {:?}", index, foo, &s));
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `index` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
12 |             scope.spawn(move || println!("thread {} doing {} while having a borrow on {:?}", index, foo, &s));
   |                         ++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0373`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 2 previous errors
```

For some reason it is unable to copy the (copyable) `index` into the the scoped thread's scope, and I do not understand why.

Is something wrong with my code, or is this a rustc (rustc 1.63.0 (4b91a6ea7 2022-08-08)) bug? Should `'1` in the error message have been replaced by something?

Comment: `move` closures are required to activate copy, otherwise they'll take the value by reference.

Comment: so there is no way to pass a loop variable into non-move closures within `scope::spawn`?

Comment: Because the loop variable may not live as long as the thread. Why not just use a move closure?

Comment: I agree with Pitaj, why not just use a move closure? Your question reads a little like "why doesn't the parameter get copied when I tell it not to get copied?"

Comment: Taking `&ImportantStruct` in the scope prevents a move

Comment: No, you can create a reference to the struct and then move in the reference. You don't need to move the struct itself in.

Comment: aah, so I need to explicitly create an `&ImportantStruct` and pass that one! I assumed that just using `&ImportantStruct` would implicitly make that happen. Thanks!

Comment: @Benni Minor nit that might not even be valid because I can't see the full context: spawning one thread per object you process might be slow and inefficient; you should look into `rayon`'s parallel iterators. They are way more efficient and scale better due to proper thread count and workstealing and so on. But of course I might be missing context.

Comment: Don't worry,  `data` has a well-chosen size smaller than my core count and the threads are running indefinitely :)
Do you know whether the `'1` in the compiler error message is supposed to be there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your main misconception is that you cannot use a `move` closure if you want to reference objects outside of the closure.

Yes, the closure moves/copies everything it uses into it. But you can create a reference to an object and then move the *reference* in. As non-mut references are implicitly `Copy`, it even lets you reuse said reference without taking ownership of it.

Like this:

```rust
use std::thread;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ImportantStruct {}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![42, 42, 42, 42];
    let s = ImportantStruct {};

    thread::scope(|scope| {
        let s_ref = &s;
        for (index, foo) in data.drain(..).enumerate() {
            scope.spawn(move || {
                println!(
                    "thread {} doing {} while having a borrow on {:?}",
                    index, foo, s_ref
                )
            });
        }
    });
}
```

```
thread 0 doing 42 while having a borrow on ImportantStruct
thread 2 doing 42 while having a borrow on ImportantStruct
thread 1 doing 42 while having a borrow on ImportantStruct
thread 3 doing 42 while having a borrow on ImportantStruct
```

---

An alternative way of writing it is to wrap the `move` closure into another context where all the variables that will get moved in get instantiated.

It's personal preference. I personally think it is easier to read because it's clear that the variables are specifically only created for the closure.

```rust
use std::thread;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ImportantStruct {}

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![42, 42, 42, 42];
    let s = ImportantStruct {};

    thread::scope(|scope| {
        for (index, foo) in data.drain(..).enumerate() {
            scope.spawn({
                let s = &s;
                move || {
                    println!(
                        "thread {} doing {} while having a borrow on {:?}",
                        index, foo, s
                    )
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

It doesn't make much difference for `FnOnce`s, but for `FnMut`s it makes things a lot cleaner.

For example, a fibonacci iterator could be written like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let fib_iter = std::iter::from_fn({
        let mut i = 0;
        let mut j = 1;
        move || {
            let i_prev = i;
            let j_prev = j;
            i = j_prev;
            j = i_prev + j_prev;
            Some(i_prev)
        }
    });

    println!("{:?}", fib_iter.take(10).collect::<Vec<_>>())
}
```

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Note that the variables `i` and `j` only exist inside of the closure, because they are created in the context that wraps it.